# Having to run Windows 10 System File Checker every few months

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, dism, sfc

My question is should I schedule a sfc /scannow on my latop once every week to prevent the startup issues I'm describing below or does anyone have any other ideas for me.

Every few months on my Windows 10 laptop (single 7200 rpm drive partitioned into 2 C: and D:) I've experienced failures to boot. The bootup process hangs on either the spinning cirlce right before the login screen loads or less frequently on the login screen or as I'm logging in. I thought these issues were due to a previous hard disk issue as I've had a few years back with a few bad sectors on the hard drive which were repaired used SeaTools. Therefore I bought a new WD black 7200 rpm drive and did a new installation using my ASUS Win 7 recovery disks (not a backup of any old data or OS but the disks that restore the computer to the state as when I purchased it) rather than installing a fresh OS. I removed all bloatware and upgraded to Win 10 and things were going great but after a few months same issue. To get the computer to boot I have to remove all external devices (HDMI to my TV, USB drive, and USB Hub) and it will usually start up after a try or two. After doing some experimentation I've found that as soon as this issue pops up I run sfc /verifyonly and there is always an issue. I then run sfc /scannow which fixes the corrupted files. Once I do that everything boots fine for the next few months. I don't bother with the DISM commands as sfc has fixed this every time.

Should I schedule sfc to run once a week to prevent this minor headache or is there any options anyone else can share who may have seen this in the past. One thing comes to mind is doing a fresh Windows 10 install w/out using the ASUS recovery disks but I don't know if I will have to pay for a new license or not.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: "My question is should I schedule a sfc /scannow on my latop once every week to prevent the startup issues I'm describing below or does anyone have any other ideas for me." - No; You should replace the storage device.  You shouldn't be running an SFC scan even once let alone do it multiple times.  **Reinstalling Windows on your device is free.**  Windows 10 will automatically detect your license and activate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that SFC finds issues about once every 5 or 6 runs or so on my various towers. I did schedule it to run once a week to prevent issues with Windows Updates. It doesn't hurt anything and I never have issues with Windows Update, startup, or any part of Windows since setting the weekly schedule. These systems all have clean installs of Windows 10 on SSD drives, not upgrade ones like your system.I also suggest a clean install after running full hardware diagnostics on your aging laptop.